# Error "custom keyword definition is invalid: data.errors should be boolean"

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, ajv

I just created a new React application using this command:

```
create-react-app mysite.com
```

After installation, when I tried to open it using `npm start` and `yarn start`, I got the following error.

```
throw new Error('custom keyword definition is invalid: '  + this.errorsText(validateDefinition.errors));
      ^

Error: custom keyword definition is invalid: data.errors should be boolean
    at Ajv.addKeyword (/Users/myAccount/Documents/Dev/Projects/ReactJS/mysite.com/node_modules/ajv/lib/keyword.js:65:13)
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe dots are not allowed in project names? That would probably cause such an error...

Comment: Thank you @Luan, I just created a new app with no dots and no capital letters: `create-react-app profilesite`, but it's still giving me same error.

Comment: You could also try to update your global installation of create-react-app to the latest version, or at least check in which version you are. Again, just a guess.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Reverting to a stable version of the ajv library also works:

```
npm uninstall ajv
npm install ajv@6.8.1
```

Answer (score 10):

I thought that was something new coming with "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.23.0". However, there's an issue with the `ajv` library.

#### Dirty fix:

In

> *node_modules\ajv-errors\index.js*

change the `errors:` parameter at line 14 from `'full'` to `true`.

#### Clean fix (temporary):

Modify your **package.json** using this:

```js
"resolutions": {
    "ajv": "6.8.1"
}
```

Comment: your clean fix should above your dirty fix imo, and this is the best answer to fix this (the clean fix version)

Answer (score 9):

Comment out `node_modules/ajv/lib/keyword.js` at line 64-65 for a workaround solution:

```
if (!validateDefinition(definition))
  throw new Error('custom keyword definition is invalid: '  + this.errorsText(validateDefinition.errors));
```

Ref: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/8768

Answer (score 3):

I get this error when I try and make a new nuxt application with npx:

```
npx create-nuxt-app <project-name>
```

I did

```
npm uninstall ajv
npm install ajv@6.8.1
```

Like @robert Rodriguez, it works, no errors.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote but what does this answer add to Robert Rodriguez's one?

Comment: For starters confirmation that it works. 2nd that React isn't the only place where this error is popping up. I'm using Nuxt and not React, maybe someone who looks up this issue for a Nuxt project they will find this helpful. 3rd His solution is simple and does not involve tweaking ajv package files. Please let us know Les if you have a better solution to this issue. I would like to see it. Thanks!

Comment: Ok thanks for the explanation, I'm sorry for bothering. (I don't have any other solution).