# Docker hub custom keyword definition is invalid: data.errors should be boolean

Tags: docker, vue.js, npm

I'm getting the same error as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54611735/custom-keyword-definition-is-invalid-data-errors-should-be-boolean), but the error only happens on the automated docker hub build, not when running the Dockerfile locally. I've tried all the solutions mentioned with no success.

[image]

Comment: The current workaround is to [install an earlier version of `ajv`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54612530/6277151). I would add that to the `Dockerfile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue related the most recent build. I fixed it by adding

```
RUN npm uninstall ajv
RUN npm install ajv@6.8.1
```

to the dockerfile. This should not longer be an issue for anyone or you are using the wrong version of ajv.